# Find the Galois group of $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

In this case, the roots of $x^3-5$ are $\{\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5},\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}\}.$ I think $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5})$ is the splitting field of $x^3-5.$ Then, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=3,$ I think the automorphisms are:
$$id$$
$$\sigma:\sigma(\sqrt[3]{5})=-\sqrt[3]{5}$$
$$\tau:\tau(\omega\sqrt[3]{5})=-\omega\sqrt[3]{5}$$
I'm not sure about what I have done. But how to determine the Galois group based on this? And how to determine the solvability of this polynomial?

Comment: Two of the roots of $x^3-5$ aren't real, so the splitting field is bigger than $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$.

Comment: note that $\sqrt[3]{25} = (\sqrt[3]{5})^2$, so $\Bbb Q(1, \sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{25})$ can be rewritten as simply $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$.  Moreover, this tells us that $\psi(\sqrt[3]{25} ) = \psi(\sqrt[3]{5} )^2$ for any Galois automorphism $\psi$.

Comment: See my edits. I did some  improvements.

Comment: Haven't you already solved the polynomial in radicals?  Doesn't this already tell you that it's solvable?

Answer (score 3):

We have the root $\sqrt[3] 5$. Now, factor $x^3-5$ using that root:
$$x^3-5=x^3-\sqrt[3] 5 x^2+\sqrt[3] 5 x^2-\sqrt[3] 25 x+\sqrt[3] {25} x-5=(x-\sqrt[3] 5)(x^2+\sqrt[3] 5 x+\sqrt[3] {25})$$

Now, the other two roots must be from this quadratic and using the quadratic formula, we can see they are not in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3] 5)$. Thus, to split $x^3-5$ in $\Bbb{Q}$, we need a root of a cubic ($\sqrt[3] 5$ from $x^3-5$) and a root of a quadratic (whatever the root of $x^2+\sqrt[3] 5 x+\sqrt[3]{25}$ is). Thus, the degree of the splitting field is $3*2=6$ and this is also the order of the Galois group.

Since this is a cubic, the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_3$. Now, what subgroup of $S_3$ has an order of $6$? The answer to that question is the Galois group.

Comment: So, the Galois group is $S_3$ right? But how to determine the solvability?

Comment: $S_3$ is a solvable group (simple factor groups are $\Bbb{A}_3=\Bbb{Z}_3$ and $\Bbb{Z}_2$), so the polynomial is solvable.

Comment: It seems like there is still some explanation needed about how we are "using the quadratic formula".  Maybe the easiest way to do this is to observe that $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is real, while the roots of the quadratic are not.

Answer (score 2):

$x^3-5$ is irreducible, so the Galois group is a transitive subgroup of $S_3$.  The only possibilities are $C_3$ and $S_3$.

But your automorphism $\tau$ has order $2$, while $C_3$ has no elements of order $2$.  So the Galois group is $S_3$.

---

We can also make a similar argument, using the Galois correspondence, by observing that $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ is contained in the splitting field, so there is a subgroup of index $2$.

Note that your claim $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ is false, in fact $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$, so the Galois group has order $6$.